# PyGame fullscreen with Title Bar (And Buttons)

Tags: button, pygame, fullscreen, titlebar

I am trying to have my `PyGame` window fullscreen, but I would like to have the buttons to close the program, and minimize the window. If this is possible in `PyGame`, please tell me how. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can change the `pygame.display.set_mode` while running, and also you can use pygame.event to check quit.

Example code:

```
import pygame,sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1440,900),pygame.FULLSCREEN,32) #Fullscreen - my display is 1440 by 900
pygame.display.set_caption("Example")
cursor_x,cursor_y = 0,0
cmddown = False
fullscreen = True
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #Toggle Fullscreen (press escape to exit/enter fullscreen)
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                if fullscreen == True:
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1440,900)) #exits fullscreen
                    pygame.display.set_caption("Example")
                    fullscreen = False
                else:
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1440,900),pygame.FULLSCREEN,32)
                    pygame.display.set_caption("Example")
                    fullscreen = True
            #Check Command + Q
            if event.key == pygame.K_LMETA:
                cmddown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                if cmddown == True:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            cmddown = False
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: If you want to quit, press LMETA (command) + Q or press the red button on top (need to exit fullscreen). If you want to toggle fullscreen on/off, press escape. If you want to minimize the window, press the yellow button on top (need to exit fullscreen). You can change the keys if you want by changing pygame.K_somekey.

Comment: I assume that "buttons" mean the colourful red/yellow/green dots on the left corner. If you want the image buttons like saying "quit", "minimize", etc., it is an entire another thing.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I want the buttons in the top right corner with the `X` to close and `-` to minimize. I am on Windows, if that changes anything